# Tratamento de Objetos em Sessão

Tags: java, jsf

Estou trabalhando com sistemas legados em JSF 1.2 e notei que os desenvolvedores fazem um uso absurdo da session para armazenar todo o tipo de objeto, que vão desde filtros informados por usuários até coleções.

Como podem imaginar, isso não é tratado de forma adequada. Muitos dos desenvolvedores usaram parâmetros e outros tipos de artifícios para minimizar a quantidade de coisas em sessão, mas infelizmente nenhum deles propôs algum tipo de padronização.

Em conversa com alguns desenvolvedores que trabalham junto comigo chegamos a conclusão que já passou da hora de padronizarmos isso, então resolvemos implementar um PhaseListener que é capaz de identificar para onde estamos indo, ficando ele responsável por eliminar objetos desnecessários da sessão.

Para que nossa solução não crie problemas, os objetos serão armazenados em sessão com uma marcação indicando que ele pode ser removido pela nossa solução.

A minha pergunta é a seguinte: Esta solução é adequada? Existe a possibilidade de que ela nos traga algum tipo de inconveniente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Infelizmente muitos desenvolvedores ao trabalhar com JSF 1.2 colocam tudo em sessão. E uma prática terrível.

Dê uma olhada nesse post: http://balusc.blogspot.com.br/2007/03/post-redirect-get-pattern.html

Ele mostra uma técnica de manter os objetos durante um request. Pelo menos pode te dar uma idéia do caminho a seguir.

Abaixo eu vou postar o código retirado de lá:

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.Map.Entry;

    import javax.faces.FacesException;
    import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
    import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
    import javax.faces.component.UIInput;
    import javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot;
    import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
    import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
    import javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent;
    import javax.faces.event.PhaseId;
    import javax.faces.event.PhaseListener;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

    /**
     * Implement the POST-Redirect-GET pattern for JSF.
     * <p>
     * This phaselistener is designed to be used for JSF 1.2 with request scoped beans of which its
     * facesmessages and input values should be retained in the new GET request. If you're using session
     * scoped beans only, then you can safely remove the <tt>saveUIInputValues()</tt> and
     * <tt>restoreUIInputValues()</tt> methods to save (little) performance. If you're using JSF 1.1,
     * then you can also remove the <tt>saveViewRoot()</tt> and <tt>restoreViewRoot</tt> methods,
     * because it is not needed with its view state saving system.
     *
     * @author BalusC
     * @link http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/03/post-redirect-get-pattern.html
     */
    public class PostRedirectGetListener implements PhaseListener {

        // Init ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        private static final String PRG_DONE_ID = "PostRedirectGetListener.postRedirectGetDone";
        private static final String SAVED_VIEW_ROOT_ID = "PostRedirectGetListener.savedViewRoot";
        private static final String ALL_FACES_MESSAGES_ID = "PostRedirectGetListener.allFacesMessages";
        private static final String ALL_UIINPUT_VALUES_ID = "PostRedirectGetListener.allUIInputValues";

        // Actions ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        /**
         * @see javax.faces.event.PhaseListener#getPhaseId()
         */
        public PhaseId getPhaseId() {

            // Only listen during the render response phase.
            return PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE;
        }

        /**
         * @see javax.faces.event.PhaseListener#beforePhase(javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent)
         */
        public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {

            // Prepare.
            FacesContext facesContext = event.getFacesContext();
            ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();
            Map<String, Object> sessionMap = externalContext.getSessionMap();

            if ("POST".equals(request.getMethod())) {

                // Save viewroot, facesmessages and UIInput values from POST request in session so that
                // they'll be available on the subsequent GET request.
                saveViewRoot(facesContext);
                saveFacesMessages(facesContext);
                saveUIInputValues(facesContext);

                // Redirect POST request to GET request.
                redirect(facesContext);

                // Set the PRG toggle.
                sessionMap.put(PRG_DONE_ID, true);

            } else if (sessionMap.containsKey(PRG_DONE_ID)) {

                // Restore any viewroot, facesmessages and UIInput values in the GET request.
                restoreViewRoot(facesContext);
                restoreFacesMessages(facesContext);
                restoreUIInputValues(facesContext);

                // Remove the PRG toggle.
                sessionMap.remove(PRG_DONE_ID);
            }
        }

        /**
         * @see javax.faces.event.PhaseListener#afterPhase(javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent)
         */
        public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
            // Do nothing.
        }

        // Helpers ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        /**
         * Save the current viewroot of the given facescontext in session. This is important in JSF 1.2,
         * because the viewroot would be lost in the new GET request and will only be created during
         * the afterPhase of RENDER_RESPONSE. But as we need to restore the input values in the
         * beforePhase of RENDER_RESPONSE, we have to save and restore the viewroot first ourselves.
         * @param facesContext The involved facescontext.
         */
        private static void saveViewRoot(FacesContext facesContext) {
            UIViewRoot savedViewRoot = facesContext.getViewRoot();
            facesContext.getExternalContext().getSessionMap()
                    .put(SAVED_VIEW_ROOT_ID, savedViewRoot);
        }

        /**
         * Save all facesmessages of the given facescontext in session. This is done so because the
         * facesmessages are purely request scoped and would be lost in the new GET request otherwise.
         * @param facesContext The involved facescontext.
         */
        private static void saveFacesMessages(FacesContext facesContext) {

            // Prepare the facesmessages holder in the sessionmap. The LinkedHashMap has precedence over
            // HashMap, because in a LinkedHashMap the FacesMessages will be kept in order, which can be
            // very useful for certain error and focus handlings. Anyway, it's just your design choice.
            Map<String, List<FacesMessage>> allFacesMessages =
                    new LinkedHashMap<String, List<FacesMessage>>();
            facesContext.getExternalContext().getSessionMap()
                    .put(ALL_FACES_MESSAGES_ID, allFacesMessages);

            // Get client ID's of all components with facesmessages.
            Iterator<String> clientIdsWithMessages = facesContext.getClientIdsWithMessages();
            while (clientIdsWithMessages.hasNext()) {
                String clientIdWithMessage = clientIdsWithMessages.next();

                // Prepare client-specific facesmessages holder in the main facesmessages holder.
                List<FacesMessage> clientFacesMessages = new ArrayList<FacesMessage>();
                allFacesMessages.put(clientIdWithMessage, clientFacesMessages);

                // Get all messages from client and add them to the client-specific facesmessage list.
                Iterator<FacesMessage> facesMessages = facesContext.getMessages(clientIdWithMessage);
                while (facesMessages.hasNext()) {
                    clientFacesMessages.add(facesMessages.next());
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Save all input values of the given facescontext in session. This is done specific for request
         * scoped beans, because its properties would be lost in the new GET request otherwise.
         * @param facesContext The involved facescontext.
         */
        private static void saveUIInputValues(FacesContext facesContext) {

            // Prepare the input values holder in sessionmap.
            Map<String, Object> allUIInputValues = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            facesContext.getExternalContext().getSessionMap()
                    .put(ALL_UIINPUT_VALUES_ID, allUIInputValues);

            // Pass viewroot children to the recursive method which saves all input values.
            saveUIInputValues(facesContext, facesContext.getViewRoot().getChildren(), allUIInputValues);
        }

        /**
         * A recursive method to save all input values of the given facescontext in session.
         * @param facesContext The involved facescontext.
         */
        private static void saveUIInputValues(
                FacesContext facesContext, List<UIComponent> components, Map<String, Object> allUIInputValues)
        {
            // Walk through the components and if it is an instance of UIInput, then save the value.
            for (UIComponent component : components) {
                if (component instanceof UIInput) {
                    UIInput input = (UIInput) component;
                    allUIInputValues.put(input.getClientId(facesContext), input.getValue());
                }

                // Pass the children of the current component back to this recursive method.
                saveUIInputValues(facesContext, component.getChildren(), allUIInputValues);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Invoke a redirect to the same URL as the current action URL.
         * @param facesContext The involved facescontext.
         */
        private static void redirect(FacesContext facesContext) {

            // Obtain the action URL of the current view.
            String url = facesContext.getApplication().getViewHandler().getActionURL(
                    facesContext, facesContext.getViewRoot().getViewId());

            try {
                // Invoke a redirect to the action URL.
                facesContext.getExternalContext().redirect(url);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Uhh, something went seriously wrong.
                throw new FacesException("Cannot redirect to " + url + " due to IO exception.", e);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Restore any viewroot from session in the given facescontext.
         * @param facesContext The involved FacesContext.
         */
        private static void restoreViewRoot(FacesContext facesContext) {

            // Remove the saved viewroot from session.
            UIViewRoot savedViewRoot = (UIViewRoot)
                    facesContext.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().remove(SAVED_VIEW_ROOT_ID);

            // Restore it in the given facescontext.
            facesContext.setViewRoot(savedViewRoot);
        }

        /**
         * Restore any facesmessages from session in the given FacesContext.
         * @param facesContext The involved FacesContext.
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        private static void restoreFacesMessages(FacesContext facesContext) {

            // Remove all facesmessages from session.
            Map<String, List<FacesMessage>> allFacesMessages = (Map<String, List<FacesMessage>>)
                    facesContext.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().remove(ALL_FACES_MESSAGES_ID);

            // Restore them in the given facescontext.
            for (Entry<String, List<FacesMessage>> entry : allFacesMessages.entrySet()) {
                for (FacesMessage clientFacesMessage : entry.getValue()) {
                    facesContext.addMessage(entry.getKey(), clientFacesMessage);
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Restore any input values from session in the given FacesContext.
         * @param facesContext The involved FacesContext.
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        private static void restoreUIInputValues(FacesContext facesContext) {

            // Remove all input values from session.
            Map<String, Object> allUIInputValues = (Map<String, Object>)
                    facesContext.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().remove(ALL_UIINPUT_VALUES_ID);

            // Restore them in the given facescontext.
            for (Entry<String, Object> entry : allUIInputValues.entrySet()) {
                UIInput input = (UIInput) facesContext.getViewRoot().findComponent(entry.getKey());
                input.setValue(entry.getValue());
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Eu cheguei a conclusão que de fato um PhaseListener é a resposta para os meus problemas. Vou adaptar esta solução e aguardar alguma outra resposta aqui no site. Mas valeu, creio que seja por ai mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que o ideal no seu caso não seria criar um "Garbage Collector" para eliminar os objetos desnecessários da sessão. Primeiro porque essa solução não seria nada simples e segundo porque objetos devem ser colocados nos seus escopos corretos, sendo eliminados de acordo.

Recomendo revisar cada caso em que um objeto é armazenado na sessão e, então, utilizar o escopo adequado para tal: página, request, etc. Deixando na sessão somente o que diz respeito à ela, como por exemplo informações de login do usuário.

Pesquise sobre os diferentes tipos de escopo. Você pode começar por esse [link](http://www.pletax.com/2013/02/entendendo-os-escopos-no-jsf-javaserver-faces/) e depois buscar exemplos e entender onde cada tipo de dado deve ficar. Com certeza sua aplicação terá um desempenho muito melhor depois desse [refactoring](http://sobrecodigo.com/em-time-que-esta-ganhando-se-mexe-sim-refactoring-basico/), em vez de adicionar mais código ainda.

Comment: Cara, eu conheço bem os escopos e certamente o ViewScope ajudaria muito na maioria dos casos. Infelizmente o JSF 1.2 trabalha apenas com Request, Application e Session. Todos os Beans utilizados neste sistemas são do tipo Request.

Comment: Hmm... Desculpa, acho que fui um pouco precipitado. =P
Só trabalhei com JSF 2, então não sabia dessa limitação de escopos. Mas achei esse [post](http://mshawally.blogspot.com.br/2012/06/view-scope-in-jsf-12-using-richfaces.html) aqui, quem sabe ajude no seu caso. =D